# как передать контекст html?

Tags: html, python, django

мне надо передать контекст НА html В html:
допустим надо передать: "< b>Hello world!< /b>"
и на страничке это отображается ТОЧНО ТАК ЖЕ, т.е. гипертекст не обрабатывается. Вот код:

```
def index(request):                 #view main page
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'title': "Главная", 'cont': "<b>Hello world</b>"})
```

вот что на html страничке:

[image: вот так отображается на html]

[image: вот что в коде html странички]

Пожалуйста подскажите что делать!

Answer (score 1):

> Питання некоректне! Правильніше буде 'Відображення змінної шаблону як
>   HTML'

Для Django

```
{{ cont | safe }}
```

або

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ cont }}
{% endautoescape %}
```